# Time tracker plugin for redmine 2.3

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

We have upgraded Redmine from version 2.2 to 2.3.
redmine_time_tracker plugin doesn't support Redmine version 2.3.
Can anyone please provide a solution to port the time_tracker plugin to Redmine version 2.3.

Answer (score 2):

This should work. It works for me on Redmine version 2.4.1.

https://github.com/mohikaner/redmine_time_tracker